# String concatenation issue c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I was working on three layer architecture. I need to pass the server name in Data Access Layer form the UI through Business Layer. For passing value I'm using properties and I'm successfully getting the value in my Data Layer. But when I try to concatenate the string to generate the data source for my database connectivity it passes null value.

My code:

```
public class dataLayer: IDisposable
{
    private string serverName;
    private string name;
    private string ceConnString;

    public string ServerName 
    {
        get { return serverName; }
        set { serverName = value; }
    }

    public dataLayer()
    {
        //First Try - Using Simple Concatination
        name = @"\\" + ServerName + @"\foldername\Database.sdf;";
        //result - name = \\\\\\foldername\Database.sdf

        //Second Try - Using String Builder
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        build.Append("\\\\");
        build.Append(ServerName);
        build.Append("\\foldername\\Database.sdf;");
        string namebuilder = build.ToString();
        //result - namebuilder = \\\\\\foldername\Database.sdf

        //Third Try - Using Path
        string line = Path.Combine("\\\\", ServerName, \\foldername\\Database.sdf;");
        //result - line = \\\\\\foldername\Database.sdf

        ceConnString = "data source=" + name;
    }
```

I want the output as **\\server name\foldername\Database.sdf**

Comment: Where do you initialize `ServerName`?

Comment: Why do you use and reject `@""` between attempt 1 and 2? Or is that just in the *trying*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the constructor of your class the instance property ServerName is still at its default value (null), you need to change the constructor in this way

```
public dataLayer(string serverName)
{
    this.ServerName = serverName;

    name = @"\\" + ServerName + @"\foldername\Database.sdf;";
    ....

}
```

and call you class in this way

```
dataLayer dl = new dataLayer(yourServerName);
```

Comment: Simple concatenation is OK with no extra context. However, it is recommended to use a `StringBuilder` or `String.Format` if there is any possibility that the multiple string construction that happens in the background of simple concatenation will lead to inefficiency. The above would be: `String.Format(@"\\{0}\foldername\Database.sdf",ServerName);`

Comment: Is there any way to do this without constructor

Comment: @CodeBeard wrong. StringBuilder makes sense only when you don't know how many strings are you trying to concatenate. With 3 concatenations it is more efficient to use the simple + operator or string.Concat   http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat

Comment: @Steve - OK. I can accept that in a 'context free' scenario and ^5 your string.Concat suggestion - I have learnt something. Would you accept a `String.Format` version as a valid option for, at least, clarity?

Comment: @user1665570 you could change your property to static and initialize it before the instance, but really I don't see any advantage in this. Only one more thing to remember when you use that class

Comment: @user1665570 irt: constructor. ^5 that under the `Principle of least surprise` (http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch11s01.html) - the `servername` is a dependency .

Comment: @CodeBeard I like string.Format and I use it often for the same reasoning 'for clarity', but keep in mind that the observations on efficiency stands. However, I prefer clarity over efficiency in this micro context

Answer (score 0):

Though you might wanna use string.Format for this, I think it's cleaner to build paths using the Path class. You almost had it using that, but you're getting extra \'es because you didn't expect the extra \'es that Path.Combine inserts between segments. Try this (in a unit test):

```
var unc = Path.Combine(@"\\", ServerName, @"foldername\Database.sdf");

Assert.AreEqual(@"\\MyHost\foldername\Database.sdf", unc);
```

Comment: I think the implied test driven approach should be commented on here. @user1665570 - using TDD really helps in these scenarios. It will expose your coupling and why `ServerName` is a dependency.

Comment: Actually I can't use AreEqual method because I will get different server name. I'm connecting it remotely over a network.

Comment: @user1665570 your unit test should have the necessary context or mocks explicitly given. So you can test what the code does in isolation and would not need the network.

Comment: The point wasn't really tdd nor the Assert. That's just how I like to confirm that my logic works. You can simply inspect the unc variable in the debugger if you prefer that.